# Reading data from text file depending on column number in each row of text file

Tags: c#, xml, file, filestream, streamreader

I am getting a text file from the client which has multiple rows and each row can belong to a group. Each group will have specific data format. Each data format defines what field will be present at specific positions in a row. I need to reformat the data and add details to each line.

For example, there are 3 groups `GroupA`, `GroupB`, `GroupC` and for each group format is specified by line numbers.

I will know before hand `GroupA` will have ID from 1-5, then space 6-8 and Date on 9-15 and Space on 16-18 and group identifier on 19 (like A/B/C) followed by spaces and group specific data.

Text file format:

```
1234G   21122013   A   12.34INR   160EUR   -12.90Adj

1254G   21122011   B   12.34Adj   22122011   160EUR   -12.90Adj

1264G   21122012   A   12.34INR   160EUR   -12.90Adj

1274G   20122013   C   FEECredit   12.34INR   -12.90Adj   160EUR   ABCDXYZ   AAA
```

So by reading 19th position of each line I can identify the group and then process the line according to the field structure of that group.

What is the best way to read this. At present I'm thinking of storing the information in XML which will have Field starting position and field length for each group. Reading each line I need to identify the group and then pick the correct XML and read field as specified in XML.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A non-XML approach I would use, would be to read in all lines into a `List<string>` first, and then process the lines one by one. By splitting each line at a space, you will have all identifiers (A/B/C) in the same index in an array. Check this identifier and process the rest of the line accordingly. Here´s a short example:

```
private void ProcessLines(List<string> lines)
{
    // lines holds the previously read lines from the textfile
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts[2] == "A")
        {
            // code to process a line of code in Group A, etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, This would have been appropriate if data in each line was less. Specific to a group there are minimum 10-12 fields in each line and i just know the starting position and length of each field in the line. So there will be lot of conditions and hardcoding.
With XML it can hold information about each group, fields starting position and length.